# huggingface_hub.utils._validators.HFValidationError:Repo id must be in zhe form 'repo_name' or 'namespace/repo_name'

Tags: python

ltp = LTP("/local_model_path")
Falid:with error:huggingface_hub.utils._validators.HFValidationError:Repo id must be in zhe form 'repo_name' or 'namespace/repo_name'

except  big guy to answer the question。ltp.**version** == 4.2.10

Comment: Why would anyone answer this question? You've put in no effort and demonstrate no attempt to understand the problem, you didn't even try to explain the issue you were having. Some people.